# Independent set queries with preprocessing

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory, graph-algorithms, query-complexity, independent-set

Suppose we have a sparse undirected graph $G = (V, E)$ with $|E| = O(|V|)$, and we want to process it and then answer queries of the following type: given a set $A$, is it an independent set in the graph.

The naive solution answers queries in time $O(|A|^2)$, by checking each pair of vertices in $A$ and making sure it isn't an edge. Are there faster algorithms? Was there any research done on this problem? I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Very good points, @Laakeri. Please consider turning them into an answer.

Comment: @ViniciusdosSantos Done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the graph is uniformly sparse in the sense that every subgraph with $n$ vertices contains at most $d \cdot n$ edges for some small $d$, then degeneracy ordering could be exploited to have $O(|E|)$ time preprocessing and $O(d \cdot |A|)$ time queries. In particular, one can record at most $d$ ``forward-edges'' for each vertex, and then check only these forward edges for adjacencies within $A$.

On the other hand, $O(|E|)$ time preprocessing and $O(|A|)$ time queries in the general case seem unlikely: If we would have such an algorithm, then we could check if the graph contains a triangle in $O(|E|)$ time. This would be a breakthrough result, and could violate some assumptions in fine-grained complexity. (I'm not really an expert in this, you should try to search for assumptions related to triangle finding.)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I see the argument in the second paragraph -- how can you use the independent set structure to check if the graph contains a triangle?

Comment: @a3nm a graph contains a triangle if and only if there exists a vertex whose neighborhood is not an independent set.

Comment: OK, so you do one query for the neighborhood of each vertex, total query time is $O(|E|)$. I see, thanks!